# Image Resizing while adding multiple images in excel using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am inserting bargraph in excel adjacent to a table in excel.For every row of the table there is a bargraph.For example say a table consists of four rows in that case four bargraphs are drawn using jfreechart and inserted in the excel.The bargraphs are to be inserted adjacent to one another.Now my problem is that the image is resized and disorted when added to excel.I did try many things but they do not work.Can any one guide me.I dont want the image to be resized.I am inserting a 450x350 jpeg images.Also the image is disorted.

the code that i have written is

```
          CreateResearchBarGraph bargraph=new CreateResearchBarGraph(barGraphValues);
          CategoryDataset dataset=bargraph.createDataset(barGraphValues);
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream=bargraph.createChart(dataset);

          byte[] imgtoArray=outputStream.toByteArray();


          int pict=xlsWorkbook.addPicture(imgtoArray,HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

          HSSFPatriarch drawing=firstSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

          HSSFClientAnchor  my_anchor=new HSSFClientAnchor(0,0,0,155,(short)1,2,(short)7,4);
          my_anchor.setAnchorType(HSSFClientAnchor.MOVE_DONT_RESIZE);
          my_anchor.setCol1(getCellVal);
          my_anchor.setRow1(i);

          System.out.println("Get anchor type "+my_anchor.getAnchorType());
          HSSFPicture hssfpic=drawing.createPicture(my_anchor, pict);

          hssfpic.resize(1.0);
          getCellVal +=7;
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with your coding attempt, it would help you for a quicker resolution.

Comment: I have been able to stop resizing the image but the image disortion continues.Can anyone please guide as to what needs to be done.